# How do you derive the backward differentiation formula of 3rd order using interpolating polynomials?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

It was my exam question, and I could not answer it. How do you drive the backward differentiation formula of 3rd order (BDF3) using interpolating polynomials?  I only knew how to derive it using the undetermined coefficients method.

BDF3 : $x_{n+1} = \frac{18}{11}x_{n} - \frac{9}{11}x_{n-1} + \frac{2}{11}x_{n-2} + \frac{6}{11}hx_{n+1}$

Comment: Generally, you interpolate and then compute whatever derivative or integral you want from that polynomial. There is not enough context in your question to answer more specifically.

Comment: I think the context is already there, if you know where to do look at. "Interpolating polynomials" and "Drive BDF3". That is all the needed keywords.

Comment: Sure, and the answerer (TroyHaskin) understood what exactly you wanted, right?

Comment: Not really. He has not used "polynomials interpolation". I think we must set all point intervals in respect to $x_1$ and $h$ like $x_2 = 2h$, $x_0 = -h$, $x_{n-1} = -2h$ and so on. Then we must plug those terms with $h$ into "interpolating polynomial formula", and then integrate all terms. (Integration here is just change the summation symbol into the integration. I am not sure though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll start with the way I think you know and then discuss the method which uses explicit interpolation scheme. I'll note that the differences are mostly semantic and lead to the same answer, but it never hurts to know how to approach a problem from multiple angles.

---

Let's say we want to find the value of $x_{n+1}$ that balances the differential equation

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}=f(t,x)
$$

at $t=t_{n+1}$ given we know $x_{n-2}$, $x_{n-1}$, and $x_{n}$ at times $t_{n-2} = t_{n+1}- 3 \Delta{t}$, $t_{n-1} = t_{n+1}- 2 \Delta{t}$, and $t_{n} = t_{n+1}- \Delta{t}$, respectively, and we have no closed form for $x(t)$.

One way to approach the problem is to express the derivative of $x(t)$ on the left-hand side of the ODE as a linear combination of the three values we know in addition to the value we're searching for:

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}\bigg\rvert_{t_{n+1}} = \omega_{n+1} x_{n+1} + \omega_{n} x_{n} + \omega_{n-1} x_{n-1} + \omega_{n-2} x_{n-2}.
$$

In order to determine the coefficients of the combination, we can replace the known values with suitable Taylor Expansions about $t_{n+1}$:

$$
\begin{align}
x_{n}   &= x_{n+1} + (-1\Delta{t}) \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}\bigg\rvert_{t_{n+1}} + \frac{(-1\Delta{t})^2}{2!} \frac{\mathrm{d}^2 x}{\mathrm{d}t^2}\bigg\rvert_{t_{n+1}} + \frac{(-1\Delta{t})^3}{3!} \frac{\mathrm{d}^3 x}{\mathrm{d}t^3}\bigg\rvert_{t_{n+1}} + \mathcal{O}(\Delta{t}^{4}) \\
x_{n-1} &= x_{n+1} + (-2\Delta{t}) \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}\bigg\rvert_{t_{n+1}} + \frac{(-2\Delta{t})^2}{2!} \frac{\mathrm{d}^2 x}{\mathrm{d}t^2}\bigg\rvert_{t_{n+1}} + \frac{(-2\Delta{t})^3}{3!} \frac{\mathrm{d}^3 x}{\mathrm{d}t^3}\bigg\rvert_{t_{n+1}} + \mathcal{O}(\Delta{t}^{4}) \\
x_{n-2} &= x_{n+1} + (-3\Delta{t}) \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}\bigg\rvert_{t_{n+1}} + \frac{(-3\Delta{t})^2}{2!} \frac{\mathrm{d}^2 x}{\mathrm{d}t^2}\bigg\rvert_{t_{n+1}} + \frac{(-3\Delta{t})^3}{3!} \frac{\mathrm{d}^3 x}{\mathrm{d}t^3}\bigg\rvert_{t_{n+1}} + \mathcal{O}(\Delta{t}^{4})
\end{align}.
$$

As will be shown, the expansions were carried out to third-order to create a solvable (square) system.  For other numerical methods, the number of needed Taylor Expansions (in this problem, three) and needed order (in this problem, again, three) may increase or decrease as needed to effect a solution.

As an aside, by examining the pattern from the expansions above, it is easy to see that for this constant $\Delta{t}$ problem, the general form of the Taylor Expansions is

$$
x_{n-k} = x_{n+1} + \sum_{m=1}^p \frac{[-(k+1) \Delta{t}]^m}{m!} \frac{\mathrm{d}^m x}{\mathrm{d}t^m}\bigg\rvert_{t_{n+1}} + \mathcal{O}(\Delta{t}^{p+1}),
$$

where for this problem, $k \in \{0,1,2\}$ (mapping to $x_n$, $x_{n-1}$, and $x_{n-2}$) and $p = 3$ for the third order expansions. This generalization is limited to only constant $\Delta{t}$ methods but can be used in computer algebra systems to create generic code to calculating various other order methods for these systems. Aside over.

Substituting these three Taylor Expansion equalities into the linear combination gives

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}\bigg\rvert_{t_{n+1}} =
    &\left[\omega_{n+1}  + \omega_{n} +                 \omega_{n-1} +                 \omega_{n-2}\right] x_{n+1} \\
    &\left[(-1\Delta{t})   \omega_{n} + (-2\Delta{t})   \omega_{n-1} + (-3\Delta{t})   \omega_{n-2}\right] \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}\bigg\rvert_{t_{n+1}} \\
    &\left[\frac{(-1\Delta{t})^2}{2!} \omega_{n} + \frac{(-2\Delta{t})^2}{2!} \omega_{n-1} + \frac{(-3\Delta{t})^2}{2!} \omega_{n-2}\right] \frac{\mathrm{d}^2x}{\mathrm{d}t^2}\bigg\rvert_{t_{ n+1}} \\
    &\left[\frac{(-1\Delta{t})^3}{3!} \omega_{n} + \frac{(-2\Delta{t})^3}{3!} \omega_{n-1} + \frac{(-3\Delta{t})^3}{3!} \omega_{n-2}\right] \frac{\mathrm{d}^3x}{\mathrm{d}t^3}\bigg\rvert_{t_{ n+1}}
&+ \mathcal{O}(\Delta{t}^{4})
\end{align}.
$$

In the above expression, there is a first-order derivative at $n+1$ on the left-hand side and several different orders of derivatives on the right-hand side.
In order to give the best approximation, we seek weights that zero the coefficients of the zeroth-, second-, and third-order derivatives and gives a coefficient of one for the first-order derivative:
$$
\begin{align}
\omega_{n+1}  + \omega_{n} +                 \omega_{n-1} +                 \omega_{n-2} &= 0 \\[1em]
(-1\Delta{t})   \omega_{n} + (-2\Delta{t})   \omega_{n-1} + (-3\Delta{t})   \omega_{n-2} &= 1 \\[1em]
\frac{(-1\Delta{t})^2}{2!} \omega_{n} + \frac{(-2\Delta{t})^2}{2!} \omega_{n-1} + \frac{(-3\Delta{t})^2}{2!} \omega_{n-2} &= 0 \\[1em]
\frac{(-1\Delta{t})^3}{3!} \omega_{n} + \frac{(-2\Delta{t})^3}{3!} \omega_{n-1} + \frac{(-3\Delta{t})^3}{3!} \omega_{n-2} &= 0
\end{align}.
$$

This can be expressed as a square, linear system:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1& 1&1&1\\
0&-1\Delta{t} & -2\Delta{t} & -3\Delta{t}\\
0& \frac{1}{2!}(-1\Delta{t})^2 &\frac{1}{2!}(-2\Delta{t})^2&\frac{1}{2!}(-3\Delta{t})^2\\
0& \frac{1}{3!}(-1\Delta{t})^3 & \frac{1}{3!}(-2\Delta{t})^3 &  \frac{1}{3!}(-3\Delta{t})^3
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\omega_{n+1}\\\omega_{n}\\\omega_{n-1}\\\omega_{n-2}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\1\\0\\0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

The solution of this system leads to the linear combination:

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}\bigg\rvert_{t_{n+1}} = \frac{1}{\Delta{t}} \left(\frac{11}{6} x_{n+1} - 3 x_{n} + \frac{3}{2} x_{n-1} - \frac{1}{3} x_{n-2}\right) + \mathcal{O}(\Delta{t}^4)
$$

where the equality becomes approximate when the higher-order terms are omitted.

---

Another approach to take is to use the information we have and the conditions we want to form a local cubic approximation to $x(t)$. Consider the following polynomial

$$
\hat{x}(t) = c_0 + c_1 (t - t_{n+1})  + c_2 (t - t_{n+1})^2  + c_3 (t - t_{n+1})^3.
$$

If $\hat{x}(t)$ exactly matches the three points we know in addition to the value we're searching for at their associated times, it may be a good approximation of $x(t)$ close to $t_{n+1}$.  And if $\hat{x}(t)$ is a good approximation, it's derivative may approximately balance the ODE at $t_{n+1}$:

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}\bigg\rvert_{t_{n+1}} \approx \frac{\mathrm{d}\hat{x}}{\mathrm{d}t}\bigg\rvert_{t_{n+1}} = c_1
$$

Note that because we're clever and centered the polynomial on $t_{n+1}$, only the $c_1$ coefficient remains after evaluation of the derivative at that time.

Through the four requirements on the polynomial to match our four points-of-interest, we can form the linear system

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & -1 \Delta{t} & (-1 \Delta{t})^2 & (-1 \Delta{t})^3\\
1 & -2 \Delta{t} & (-2 \Delta{t})^2 & (-2 \Delta{t})^3\\
1 & -3 \Delta{t} & (-3 \Delta{t})^2 & (-3 \Delta{t})^3
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
c_0 \\ c_1 \\ c_2 \\ c_3
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{n+1} \\ x_n \\ x_{n-1} \\ x_{n-2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and obtain the value of the needed coefficient

$$
c_1 = \frac{1}{\Delta{t}} \left(\frac{11}{6} x_{n+1} - 3 x_{n} + \frac{3}{2} x_{n-1} - \frac{1}{3} x_{n-2}\right)
$$

This answer agrees with the approximation from the Taylor Expansion method after neglecting higher-order terms.

---

Both are valid approximations and merely differ in how the problem is approached:

- Directly approximate the derivative of an unknown function with values we know and a cubic Taylor approximation about the point-of-interest.
- Directly approximate the unknown function with values we know using a cubic polynomial and evaluate its derivative at the point-of-interest.

---

Would the answer be the same if we used a different basis for the interpolation such as [Lagrange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) versus the above [Monomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomial_basis)?  It shouldn't since all one-dimensional interpolating polynomials of degree $n$ [are unique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation#Uniqueness_of_the_interpolating_polynomial) given $n+1$ interpolation points.  But let's check.

Consider the following polynomial

$$
\hat{x}(t) = \sum_{j=-2}^{1}\,\prod_{\substack{-2\le m \le 1\\ m \neq j}}
\frac{t - t_{n+m}}{t_{n+j} - t_{n+m}} \,x_{n+j}
$$

It would be rather verbose and tedious to look at all of the terms, so let's focus on the $j = 1$ term of the polynomial:

$$
\frac{(t-t_{n})(t-t_{n-1})(t-t_{n-2})}{(t_{n+1}-t_n)(t_{n+1}-t_{n-1})(t_{n+1}-t_{n-2})} x_{n+1}
$$

We can compress the denominator to $6 \Delta{t}^3$ since the interval $\Delta{t}$ is fixed between all points, and we note that the derivative of the product in the numerator is a summation of lower degree products:

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left[(t-t_{n})(t-t_{n-1})(t-t_{n-2})\right] = 
(t-t_{n})(t-t_{n-1}) + (t-t_{n})(t-t_{n-2}) + (t-t_{n-1})(t-t_{n-2})
$$

which is equal to $11 \Delta{t}^2$ when evaluated at $t_{n+1}$.  So the coefficient for the $x_{n+1}$ coefficient is $\tfrac{11}{6 \Delta{t}}$, which is the same as the two above results.

Performing the process for each other value of $j$ will also generate the same terms.

Comment: Thanks for the lengthy answer, I up-voted it. You used Taylor series and cubic expansion as your tools. I didn't go through the details but it seems your approach is right. I think my instructor wanted me to use  "interpolation polynomial" formula in order to drive the BDF3: $ f(x) \approx \sum_{i=0}^{n} \Big( \prod_{0 \le j \le n, j \neq i} \frac{x-x_j}{x_i - x_j} \Big)f(x_i)$ which I see you still have not used. Anyway thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Ehsan To be clear, any polynomial formed from a selected set of points is an interpolating polynomial.  However, it appears you are interested in the Lagrange form.  I added a brief description of how to perform the construction using that basis but did not go through each of the terms as it is rather tedious and very mechanical.

Comment: @TroyHaskin How did  you get the RHS column of [0 1 0 0 ] on the taylor series version?

Comment: @MathIsHard Each column represents a truncated Taylor Expansion for $x_{n-k}$. Substituting each of those columns into the previous weight equation for $\mathrm{d}x/\mathrm{d}t|_{t_n+1}$, you have a left hand-side with only a first order derivative, and a right-hand side with many orders of derivative. To make the right-hand side sum to only a single first order derivative, the load vector of the linear system must be $[0\,1\,0\,0]^T$, where each row is an increasing order of derivative (i.e., zero-th, first, second, and third).

Comment: Is it possible to use the same approach to derive a backward differentiation formula for the second and third derivative?

Comment: @Samuel Yes. As stated in the comments (though a bit unclear in the answer), the Taylor Series version right-hand side $[0\,1\,0\,0]^{T}$ creates weights that zero out the zeroth, second, and third derivatives while retaining the $1$ for the first derivative. The right-hand side can thus be changed to retain any desired order derivative by changing the placement of the $1$. Also, given an interpolating polynomial, simply take the derivative of the polynomial to your desired order of derivative, assuming the polynomial is not the zero function following the differentiation.

Comment: @TroyHaskin Thank you for the answer! I tried to derive an expression for the second derivative. But I got stuck. In the expression for the Taylor expansion above where does $k$ in $[-(k+1) \Delta{t}]^m$ come from? I'd be very happy if you could give me a hint how to derive the second derivative with the approach above!

Comment: @Samuel I expanded the Taylor Expansion derivation. To derive expressions for other orders of derivatives comes down to calculating weights that zero all orders of derivative other than the desired order. This particular problem zeros all derivative orders other than one. The $k$ is how many steps behind $n+1$ the Taylor Expansion is. I also expanded this point in the answer update.

Comment: @TroyHaskin Wow, what a great explanation! Thanks!

Comment: @TroyHaskin Can you please explain where $x_{n-k} = x_{n+1} + \sum_{m=1}^p \frac{[-(k+1) \Delta{t}]^m}{m!} \frac{\mathrm{d}^m x}{\mathrm{d}t^m}\bigg\rvert_{t_{n+1}}$ comes from? Is it the discrete Taylor series? Could you please add a link to some source? Thanks!

Comment: @Samuel There is not citation needed. It's a typical form of the Taylor Expansion with $(x-a) == -(k+1)\Delta{t}$. The equality is simply a result of the $k$-th step being integer multiples of $\Delta{t}$ behind $x_{n+1}$. In fact, I wrote the three Taylor Expansions first by-hand and then created the generalization since that is how I created and solve the equations (in Mathematica, I believe). I have inverted the discussion for more proper framing.

Comment: Perfect, now I see it. Thank you for the effort!

Comment: @TroyHaskin You mentioned that based on the problem the number of needed Taylor Expansions and the needed order varies. Can I not just use more Taylor Expansions of higher order to get better results? Or does it not work this way?

Comment: @Samuel BDF methods above sixth order are not (zero-)stable and can't be used. Further, since BDF methods are also implicit (i.e., the right hand-side function $f(t_{n+1},x_{n+1})$ is evaluated at $x_{n+1}$), they require a nonlinear solve in-general and higher-order BDF methods have more terms in the solve (not a deal breaker, but it does increase complexity). Lastly, BDF methods are not "self-starting" like Runge-Kutta Methods, so some combination of other solvers is needed to generate all needed data (all state values before $x_{n+1}$) before using the high-order BDF scheme.