# trying to derive BDF-3

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-differences

What I have so far: I really appreciate any help.. I am stuck on this. 
I want to get 
[image]

We want to determine the 3rd order 3-step BDF method 
$$\sum_{j=0}^r a_jU^{n+j}=kB_rf^{n+r} \Rightarrow a_0U^n+a_1U^{n+1}+a_2U^{n+2}+a_3B^{n+3}=kB_3f(U^{n+3})$$

We have that $$u'(t_{n+3})=\frac{1}{kB_3} \big [a_0U^n +a_1U^{n+1}+a_2U^{n+2}+a_3B^{n+3}\big ]$$\

We want to use a Taylor Series expansion about the point $t_{n+3}$:
$$U_{n+3}=U_{n+3}\tag{1}$$
Knowing that $t_{n+2}=t_{n+3}-k$, we have that

\begin{align*}
U_{n+2}&=U_{n+3}+U'_{n+3}(t_{n+3}-k-t_{n+3})+\frac{1}{2}U''_{n+3}(t_{n+3}-k-t_{n+3})^2\\&\quad+\frac{1}{6}U'''_{n+3}(t_{n+3}-k-t_{n+3})^3+O(k^4)\\
&=U_{n+3}-kU'_{n+3}+\frac{k^2}{2}U''_{n+3}-\frac{k^3}{6}U'''_{n+3}+O(k^4)\tag{2}
\end{align*}
Similarly, we can find $U_{n+1}$ and $U_{n}$.

\begin{align*}
U_{n+1}&=U_{n+3}+U'_{n+3}(t_{n+3}-2k-t_{n+3})+\frac{1}{2}U''_{n+3}(t_{n+3}-2k-t_{n+3})^2\\
&\quad+\frac{1}{6}U'''_{n+3}(t_{n+3}-2k-t_{n+3})^3+O(k^4)\\
&=U_{n+3}-2kU'_{n+3}+2k^2U''_{n+3}-\frac{8k^3}{6}U'''_{n+3}+O(k^4)\tag{3}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
U_{n}&=U_{n+3}+U'_{n+3}(t_{n+3}-3k-t_{n+3})+\frac{1}{2}U''_{n+3}(t_{n+3}-3k-t_{n+3})^2\\
&\quad+\frac{1}{6}U'''_{n+3}(t_{n+3}-3k-t_{n+3})^3+O(k^4)\\
&=U_{n+3}-3kU'_{n+3}+\frac{9k^2}{2}U''_{n+3}-\frac{27k^3}{6}U'''_{n+3}+O(k^4)\tag{4}
\end{align*}
Then we have
\begin{align*}
u'(t_{n+3})= \frac{1}{kB_3}\bigg[a_0\big[U_{n+3}-3kU'_{n+3}+\frac{9k^2}{2}U''_{n+3}-\frac{27k^3}{6}U'''_{n+3} \big] + a_1 \big[U_{n+3}-2kU'_{n+3}+2k^2U''_{n+3} \\ -\frac{8k^3}{6}U'''_{n+3} \big] +a_2 \big[U_{n+3}-kU'_{n+3}+\frac{k^2}{2}U''_{n+3}-\frac{k^3}{6}U'''_{n+3} \big]+a_3\big[U_{n+2} \big]\bigg]
\end{align*}

I think I need to solve a system of some sort. I  tried a matrix like this where a_n is a0. a_n+1 is a1, etc..

[image]

by following this post, [How do you derive the backward differentiation formula of 3rd order using interpolating polynomials?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1782499/how-do-you-derive-the-backward-differentiation-formula-of-3rd-order-using-interp)
but it didn't produce the correct solution :/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equations that I have taken the liberty of numbering $(1)$ through $(4)$ read, as a matrix equation
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\
1&-1&\frac12&-\frac16\\
1&-2&2&-\frac43\\
1&-3&\frac92&-\frac92\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}U_{n+3}\\kU_{n+3}^{\prime}\\k^2U_{n+3}^{\prime\prime}\\k^3U_{n+3}^{\prime\prime\prime}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}U_{n+3}\\U_{n+2}\\U_{n+1}\\U_n\end{bmatrix}$$
We can solve this for
$$\begin{align}kU_{n+3}^{\prime}&=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\
1&-1&\frac12&-\frac16\\
1&-2&2&-\frac43\\
1&-3&\frac92&-\frac92\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}U_{n+3}\\U_{n+2}\\U_{n+1}\\U_n\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\frac{11}6U_{n+3}-3U_{n+2}+\frac32U_{n+1}-\frac13U_n\end{align}$$
And that works out to
$$U_{n+3}-\frac{18}{11}U_{n+2}+\frac9{11}U_{n+1}-\frac2{11}U_n=\frac6{11}kU_{n+3}^{\prime}$$
As hoped for.

**EDIT**: Looking at your final matrix equation you should have gotten the same formula as I did. How did you try to solve it? There is a typo in that expression $a_3[U_{n+2}]$ but it didn't propagate into your matrix equation.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your response. I tried to solve it in matlab symbolically. :/ I have no idea how I didn’t get it either. I will take a closer look. I appreciate your response a lot though. Thank you. I will be back once I take a look.

Comment: If I had to guess, maybe I missed a parenthesis or something in  Matlab. I’ve been known to do that :/ but I will check it out. I’m just happy I had the right process at least.

Comment: Check out what [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1,1,1,1%7D,%7B0,-1,-2,-3%7D,%7B0,1%2F2,2,9%2F2%7D,%7B0,-1%2F6,-4%2F3,-9%2F2%7D%7D%5E(-1)%7B%7B0%7D,%7B1%7D,%7B0%7D,%7B0%7D%7D) does to it :)

Comment: Thank you. I have no idea why the matlab didn't work :/ But I got the process right! thank you very much for your time

Comment: @user5713492 When you solve for $kU_{n+3}^{\prime}$ how do you exactly do that? Where does the vector $\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&0\end{bmatrix}$ come from?