# Four-point forward-difference formula using Newton's form for first order derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

As input we have ${x_0 = x}$,${x_1 = x + h}$, ${x_2 = x+2h}$, ${x_3 = x+3h}$. Using the Newton's form for four points we get:
${g(x) = f_0 + (x-x_0)f[x_0,x_1] + (x-x_0)(x-x_1)f[x_0,x_1,x_2] + (x-x_0)(x-x_1)(x-x_2)f[x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3]}$

While the derivative can be computed as
${g'(x) = f[x_0,x_1] + [(x-x_0)+(x-x_1)]f[x_0,x_1,x_2] + (3x^2 - 2xx_2 - 2xx_1 + x_2x_1 - 2xx_0 + x_2x_0 + x_1x_0)f[x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3]}$

and then we can substitute ${x}$ with ${x_0}$.
I don't know how to continue with the part ${(3x^2 - 2xx_2 - 2xx_1 + x_2x_1 - 2xx_0 + x_2x_0 + x_1x_0)}$ such that it is in the same format of ${[(x-x_0)+(x-x_1)]}$, because having the differences between the points permit me to substitute them with h and compute ${f'(x)}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also compute the derivative via difference quotient
$$
\frac{g(x)-g(x_0)}{x-x_0}=f[x_0,x_1]+(x-x_1)f[x_0,x_1,x_2]
+(x−x_1)(x−x_2)f[x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3]
$$
so that then
\begin{align}
g'(x_0)&=f[x_0,x_1]+(x_0-x_1)f[x_0,x_1,x_2]
+(x_0−x_1)(x_0−x_2)f[x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3]
\\
&=
\frac{x_1-x_0}h+(-h)\frac{x_2-2x_1+x_0}{2h^2}+(-h)(-2h)\frac{x_3-3x_2+3x_1-x_0}{6h^3}\\
&=\frac{2x_3-9x_2+18x_1-11x_0}{6h}
\end{align}
See also [How do you derive the backward differentiation formula of 3rd order using interpolating polynomials?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1782499/how-do-you-derive-the-backward-differentiation-formula) on how to get the same coefficient with different methods.

Comment: Do you think it's correct to use it? Because I have to arrive to that similar form (${\frac{g(x) - g(x_0)}{x-x0}}$) at the end, that is, solving this part and only then applying the divided differences

Comment: In the end it should be the same, there are just cubic polynomials behind it, so there are no hidden pitfalls.